# need help figuring out how to compare user input and pulling data from a website using an api key

Tags: android

This is my first time programming in android studio and I need help in figuring out how to compare options selected by the user based on the radio buttons and query an api to pull data from a website. Below is the code of the layout.The results are supposed to be displayed on another page, thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0663ba"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="@string/search"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/zip_code"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.04"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/select_date_range"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup6"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/radioGroup7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/_1_week"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/_2_weeks"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/_3_months"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="@string/select_crime_type"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup7"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup6">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/rape"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton15"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/assault"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/murder"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
        android:text="@string/search_for_criminal_or_victim"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/radioGroup7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup7" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_full_name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="147dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="76dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#a91818"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/new_crime_img"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/radioGroup6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: When you click on any radio button in a radio group, you can get the selected radio button id from radio group and using that id find the string of the radio button and then use it according to your needs

Comment: you are trying to accomplish too large task at once. Split it to smaller tasks: 1) get which radiobuttons are selected by the user. 2) get data from API. 3) compare data from API to user data